# Passing dynamic values to checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

I have a couple of checkboxes in my code. The name is the same; only the values differ. Basically I am creating a search feature using `GET` request, so after clicking on the search button I want to check the checkboxes which were checked after the search button was clicked.

**HTML**

```
<?php     
foreach ($categories as $a):?>
<input type="checkbox" name="courses"  value="<?=$a['id']?>"<?=$a['course_name']?><br>
<?php endforeach;
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
str='<?=$_GET["courses"]?>';
var partsOfStr = str.split('-');

partsOfStr.forEach(function(item, index, partsOfStr) {
     $('input[type=checkbox][value=""+item+""]').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

I am receiving this error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox][value=""+item+""]

This works perfectly fine though:

```
  $('input[type=checkbox][value='2']').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Simple typo: `$('input[type=checkbox][value="'+item+'"]').prop('checked', true);` - Use this. Your quotes mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Change your syntax as below expression.

```
   $('input[type=checkbox][value='+item+']').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: `prop()` would be better here.

Comment: why my question is downvoted? looks perfectly to the point with clear explanation :/

Comment: That's not me @uneebmeer

Answer (score 2):

Simple typo. Also, use [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value="'+item+'"]').prop('checked', true);
//----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```